# how to persist google oauth signin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oauth

I have implemented google oauth sing-in in my website, the problem is that i don't know how to handle the login after user is redirected to a new page,

here is the code how i have implemented the button.

```
<div class="Sign_in_Div">
        <div class="gsignin_div">
            <div id="gSignInWrapper">
                <div id="customBtn" class="customGPlusSignIn">
                  <span class="icon"></span>
                  <span class="buttonText">Sign in with Google</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <script>startApp();</script>
        </div>

 var googleUser = {};
 var startApp = function() {
  gapi.load('auth2', function(){
  auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: '921258372597-t5jrb0e9p4ivstp9mfi972lhcvfcuo59.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
  });
  attachSignin(document.getElementById('customBtn'));
});
};

 function attachSignin(element) {
auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
    function(googleUser) {
          googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName();
                window.location.replace("http://localhost:30012/Duck/sign_/signin.html");
    }, function(error) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
    });
  }
```

as you can see after the user successfully is logged in, user is redirected to signin.html, but in there i don't know to handle the oauth

user redirected page code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="oauthc_g_d.js"></script>
 <script>function attachSignin(element) {
          console.log(googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName());
 </script>

 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Thanks for stopping by</h1>
 </body>
 </html>
```

here i don't get the console outputting username

Comment: Ive not used O Auth myself, but you'll need to persist the auth token in some sort of data store. Something like `localstorage` or `cookies` on the client side, or a PHP `$_SESSION` variable or similar on the server. What specifically you need will depend on how you want to store it

Comment: okay i got the idea, thanks that will do!